# Unable to add Header Footer on every page of pdf using DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am creating pdf by passing html to dompdf. I am trying to add header and footer on every page of the pdf. The issue is that the pdf has multiple pages. The header is created on the first page and footer on the last page. I need them both on every page.

```css
@page { 
                    margin: 0cm 0cm;
                }
                body {
                    margin-left: 1cm; 
                    margin-right: 1cm; 
                    margin-top: 1cm; 
                    margin-bottom: 1cm; 
                }
                header {
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0cm;
                    left: 0cm;
                    right: 0cm;
                    height: 1cm;

                    padding: 10px;
                    background-color: #0011ff;
                }
                footer {
                    position: fixed;
                    bottom: 0cm;
                    left: 0cm;
                    right: 0cm;
                    height: 1cm;
                    
                    padding: 10px;
                    background-color: #0011ff;
                }
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Header</p>
</header>
<div>
  <p>main content. This is just an example of how I am creating the document. This div's content spans on multiple pages.</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution from [here](https://adelabu4fred.medium.com/how-to-set-header-and-footer-in-dompdf-20389ff82299) and added `bottom: 0px;` to the footer style.
Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>   
        <style>
            @page{
                margin-top: 150px;
                margin-bottom: 150px;
            }
            header{
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                height: 150px;
                margin-top: -150px;
            }
            footer{
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                height: 150px;
                bottom: 0px;
                margin-bottom: -150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <header>
              <img src="{{public_path("images/header.jpg")}}" style="width: 100%" >
         </header>
         <footer>
              <img src="{{public_path("images/footer.jpg")}}" style="width: 100%">
         </footer>
         <main>
                   <!-- content here -->
         </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

The generated PDF had the header and footer images on all pages.

Answer (score -3):

Please add proper html tags like; You need to wrap with html and body tag to make it work. This will print header and footer in each pdf pages.

```
 <html>
    <body>    
    <header>
          <p>Header</p>
        </header>
     <footer>
          <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
        <div>
          <p>main content. This is just an example of how I am creating the document. This div's content spans on multiple pages.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```